# Specify query parameter for a single HTTP method

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

To illustrate my problem, I made a condensed example from the Apiary.io blueprint tutorial.

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Gist Fox API

# Group Gist
Gist-related resources of *Gist Fox API*.

## Gists Collection [/gists{?since}]

### List All Gists [GET]
+ Parameters
    + since (optional, string) ... Timestamp in ISO 8601 format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ` Only gists updated at or after this time are returned.

+ Response 200

        {
            items: []
        }

### Create a Gist [POST]
To create a new Gist simply provide a JSON hash of the *description* and *content* attributes for the new Gist. 

+ Request (application/json)

        {
            "description": "Description of Gist",
            "content": "String content"
        }

+ Response 201

        {
        }
```

Then in my apiary documentation I get the following:

```
GET   /gists{?since}
POST  /gists{?since}
```

However, for me it makes sense to have the `since` query parameter only for the GET request. Unfortunately I didn't find a way to achieve this result:

```
GET   /gists{?since}
POST  /gists
```

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

*(Thursday, 23 Oct 2014)*

**The fix has been deployed**; could you please give it a try and let me know if everything works as expected?

---

#### The bad news

It is our (Apiary) bug and you're not doing anything wrong :-(

#### The good news

It is a [known bug](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/40) we are currently working on and [it is going to be fixed](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/40#issuecomment-58335576) with the end of this week (Sunday, 19 Oct 2014) :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same issue. You can have a look there: http://docs.test2974.apiary.io

Comment: Perhaps the fix is valid only with the new presentation that is currently in beta?